# How can I satisfy sp_describe_first_result_set stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, business-objects

I am working on a BOBJ (Business Objects) report.  Designing this report using just query is a nightmare, therefore, we decided to create a StoredProcedure (SP) and use this SP to create the report which can be done in a snap.  However, our enthusiasm did not last long when we encounter this error:

> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Cannot find the object "#AccountReference" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
> Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> **The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these**.

This is happening because I must use temp table to convert the meta data stored as data to actual metadata.  I could not find a way to bypass the limitations as specified in [this article by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

That said, **I greatly appreciate if I can get some help from the experts to bypass the temporary table so that I can satisfy BOBJ report to get its first result set in order to build the Designer**.

**Here is my sample code**:

```sql
    --MetaData Table
IF OBJECT_ID('AccountMetaData') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE AccountMetaData
            (VarText1Caption    VARCHAR(50) NULL,
             VarText1Visible    BIT         NULL,
             VarText1Required   BIT         NULL,
             VarText2Caption    VARCHAR(50) NULL,
             VarText2Visible    BIT         NULL,
             VarText2Required   BIT         NULL,
             VarDate1Caption    VARCHAR(50) NULL,
             VarDate1Visible    BIT         NULL,
             VarDate1Required   BIT         NULL,
             VarCheck1Caption   VARCHAR(50) NULL,
             VarCheck1Visible   BIT         NULL,
             VarCheck2Caption   BIT         NULL
            )

            INSERT INTO AccountMetaData (VarText1Caption, VarText1Visible, VarText1Required, VarDate1Caption, VarDate1Visible, VarDate1Required, VarCheck1Caption, VarCheck1Visible, VarCheck2Caption)
                VALUES ('Bill To Nike', 1, 0, 'Billed On', 1, 0, 'Exportable', 1, 1)
    END

    SELECT * FROM AccountMetaData;

    --Data Table    
IF OBJECT_ID('AccountReference') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE AccountReference
            ( TextColumn1   VARCHAR(50) NULL,
              TextColumn2   VARCHAR(50) NULL,
              DateColumn1   DATETIME    NULL,
              BitColumn1    BIT  NULL 
            )
    
            INSERT INTO AccountReference (TextColumn1, TextColumn2, DateColumn1, BitColumn1)
                                   SELECT '1234567890', NULL, dateadd(m, -1, getdate()),  1
                                   UNION
                                   SELECT '1234567891', NULL, dateadd(m, -2, getdate()),  0
                                   UNION
                                   SELECT '123456790', NULL, dateadd(m, -3, getdate()),  1
    END                        
    --  DELETE FROM AccountReference;

    SELECT * FROM AccountReference;

    -- STORED PROCEDURE

CREATE PROCEDURE GetData 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @TextColumn1 VARCHAR(50)
              , @TextColumn2 VARCHAR(50)
              , @DateColumn1 VARCHAR(50)
              , @BitColumn1 VARCHAR(50)

        SELECT @TextColumn1 = VarText1Caption
             , @TextColumn2 = VarText2Caption
             , @DateColumn1 = VarDate1Caption
             , @BitColumn1 = VarCheck1Caption
            FROM AccountMetaData 

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AccountReference

        CREATE TABLE #AccountReference
            ( TextColumn1   VARCHAR(50)
            , TextColumn2   VARCHAR(50)
            , DateColumn1   DATETIME2
            , BitColumn1        BIT
            )

        INSERT INTO #AccountReference (TextColumn1, TextColumn2, DateColumn1, BitColumn1)
            SELECT TextColumn1
                 , TextColumn2
                 , DateColumn1
                 , BitColumn1
            FROM AccountReference

        IF (@TextColumn1 IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename N'#AccountReference.TextColumn1', @TextColumn1, N'COLUMN';
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                ALTER TABLE #AccountReference DROP COLUMN TextColumn1;
            END 

        IF (@TextColumn2 IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename N'#AccountReference.TextColumn2', @TextColumn2, N'COLUMN';
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                ALTER TABLE #AccountReference DROP COLUMN TextColumn2;
            END
            
        IF (@DateColumn1 IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename N'#AccountReference.DateColumn1', @DateColumn1, N'COLUMN';
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                ALTER TABLE #AccountReference DROP COLUMN DateColumn1;
            END

        IF (@BitColumn1 IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_rename N'#AccountReference.BitColumn1', @BitColumn1, N'COLUMN';
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                ALTER TABLE #AccountReference DROP COLUMN BitColumn1;
            END

    SELECT * FROM #AccountReference
END
GO

    -- SAP BOBJ REPORT first result set CALL  ******* this is internal to the BOBJ report
exec [sys].sp_describe_first_result_set N'exec GetData',NULL,1
```

> --Error returned from above call due to unsupported types [as specified in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Cannot find the object "#AccountReference" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
> Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem.  Why are you creating the object `#AccountReference` and then changing the name of some of the columns? Just give them the right name in the first place when you create the object.

Comment: @Larnu I don't have that luxury my friend.  Like it is shown in the example, the actual column names are in one table and their corresponding data is in another table.  This done for customization requested by the customers.  So, the metadata is DYNAMIC based on what the customer set.

Comment: Then this most certainly sounds like an XY problem, @Vincy. Sounds like you need to take a step back and do some redesigning. If it's just the columns that need "dynamic" names, then that's application logic, not RDBMS.

Comment: BusinessObjects cannot run a query that creates/modifies anything or contains dynamic SQL; not even if it is within a stored procedure. I don't see a way to solve for this with just BOBJ. Perhaps you could run the stored procedure external to BOBJ and then run the report.

Comment: See also: https://pastebin.com/raw/uYP3YNS3